# How to Open ChildPage's Modal Popup on Parent Page?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup, parent

[image]

How to Open ChildPage's Modal Popup on Parent Page? As shown in the picture, parent page got two childpage, green and blue. The modal popup appear on the green page. How to Open ChildPage's Modal Popup on Parent Page(In the center) ?

Comment: What language/framework are you intending to use? Cheers

Comment: I using Javascripts and html only

Answer (score 0):

Look into `window.postMessage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

In the child, do something like this as the onClick handler on the button:

```
function openParentModal() {
   parent.postMessage("openModal", "http://targetorigin.com") // Change origin
}
```

In parent:

```
function receiveMessage(event) {
   if (event.origin !== "http://targetorigin.com") // Change origin
      return;

   if(event.data == "openModal") { 
      openModal()
   }
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

Comment: Okay, I try it first, later tell you the result.

Comment: Friend, your suggestion is put the modal div (openModal) in parent page, but what i desire is put the modal div in child page, but appear at the center of the parent page. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Thats not possible, since you are limited to the height and width of the iframe. In the parent page you have the full browser window to place the modal.